# BDD for text is a specific color?

Tags: bdd, behat, mink, gherkin

I'm working on describing a feature where we want to use color to signify a positive or negative number,  where negative is red, positive is black. It's basically like this:

```
Given I bought 2 items
Then I have returned 1 item
Then on the return receipt I should see both items and their costs
And these lines should be black
Then below that I should see the item I return and it's cost as a negative number
And that line should be red
```

Since Behat/Mink can't do this yet, how might I test this? And is it something that really needs to be tested? My thought is since this is the feature that describes to the developer how the site should work, if I don't put it in here, how do they know that returned items need to be shown in red?

Ideas? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The colors are an implementation detail that don't have a place in the scenario. The important thing is that the return receipt tells you about

1. The original purchase
2. The returned item

So I'd write the scenario as

```
Given I purchased two items
And I returned one of the items
When I view the return reciept
Then I should see two items were purchased
And I should see that one item was returned
```

Now when you product owner decides that having a returned item as red isn't sufficient, and that it needs to be in a box with 'returned' as the title, you won't have to rewrite your scenario

Comment: But why wouldn't you rewrite the scenario? The site has changed, shouldn't the test?

Comment: No, lets investigate some potential changes. Say the change is really minor, our error text goes from red to blue.This change requires: rewriting all the tests that mention the color red, a minute change to some css, and a complete rebuild. This is quite a bit more expensive than just changing one css variable. Our scenario has increased the cost of change. Is, is this cost worth paying? I don't think it is. Now consider if we change the mechanism of presentation e.g. errors in a red box with white text, should we rewrite the scenario to reflect that?

Comment: We currently have steps that say things like "I should see an error message" or even sometimes "i should see an error message containing `text`" so the developers know exactly what should happen. Then we only have one step that checks that the error message was actually in a div with class alert-error. 

This was a unique situation where we were trying to demonstrate accounting type transactions, black = money in, red = money out, and needed to communicate to the devs not only to do that but confirm they did it